# get all inherited properties by function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, properties

without using funtion, when i use for (var prop in obj) which will show me all value in the object. However when i tried to put in function, it just show up me with the first value in the object which not show me the second element ( studentID ). :(

```js
var target = document.getElementById("outputArea");
var outstring = " ";

var myObj = {
 name: "Nguyen Viet Tien",
 StudentID: "26813157",
};

function tellAll(obj) {
 var dis = " ";
 
 for(var prop in obj) {
  dis += "first property is" + prop + "with the content" + obj[prop] + "<br/>"; 
  return dis;
 }
}

outstring += tellAll(myObj);
target.innerHTML = outstring;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Eng1003 Workshop Code Week 04</title>
 <style>
  #outputArea {
   padding: .25em;
   border: solid black 2px;
   margin: 3em;   
   height: 20em;
   width: 20em;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   font-family: arial "sans serif";
   font-size: 1em;
   color: rgb(50, 50, 250);
   background-color: rgb(225,225,225) ;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="outputArea"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you put the `return` statement in the middle of the `for` loop, so the function will return before it finishes the first iteration.

Comment: If you format your code well, the issue can be easily find out.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

return statement in the wrong place

```
function tellAll(obj) {
    var dis = " ";

    for(var prop in obj) {
        dis += "first property is" + prop + "with the content" + obj[prop] + "<br/>";   
    }

    return dis;
}
```